# MySQL: LOAD DATA INFILE producing incorrect table results

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, mysql-workbench, innodb

I am trying to use LOAD DATA INFILE to load my data into tables.

My table:

```
Alcohol name varchar(45)
Type varchar(45)
ABV FLOAT
Brewery INT(11)
Average Price DOUBLE
Description VARCHAR(1000)
```

My CSV file looks like:

```
Alcohol name,Type,ABV,Brewery,Average Price,Description
Hocus Pocus,Beer,4.5,812,0,"Our take on a classic summer ale.  A toast to weeds, rays, and summer haze.  A light, crisp ale for mowing lawns, hitting lazy fly balls, and communing with nature, Hocus Pocus is offered up as a summer sacrifice to clodless days.Its malty sweetness finishes tart and crisp and is best apprediated with a wedge of orange."
Grimbergen Blonde,Beer,6.699999809,264,0,None
Widdershins Barleywine,Beer,9.100000381,779,0,None
Lucifer,Beer,8.5,287,0,None
Bitter,Beer,4,1056,0,None
Winter Warmer,Beer,5.199999809,1385,0,None
Winter Welcome 2007-2008,Beer,6,1099,0,None

etc....
```

My LOAD Command looks like:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/leo/CS336/Tables/beers.csv' INTO TABLE Alcohol FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

The garbage table I'm getting looks like:

```
Alcohol name Type  ABV Brewery Average Price Description
Golden Ale  NULL    0   0   NULL NULL   
* 10.5% (2008)  NULL    0   0   NULL NULL       
* 15.5 gallon keg   NULL    0   0       NULL NULL   
* 22 oz. bottles    NULL    0   0   NULL NULL       
* 5.17 gallon keg   NULL    0   0   NULL NULL       
* 9.78% (2007)"     NULL    0   0   NULL NULL   
* Available March through August    NULL    0   0       NULL NULL   
etc...
```

Comment: Your CSV file isn't a csv file (it looks like excel) - can you add the first 4 rows of your actual csv file (the one with the commas) as text to the question. You might also try adding the lines terminated by option to your load statement '\n' or possibly '\r\n'

Comment: It is a csv, excel supports csv types. I could post the txt file but it would be the same effect. I'll try '\n' and '\r\n'.

Comment: If you post it as a csv text file then we can play with it and come up with a solution but to be honest I cannot be bothered to retype the data.

Comment: @P.Salmon done. sorry about that

Comment: You have commas in the description field. Add also `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'`. Other trick I did was that I had a temporary table with all varchars and I made sure I load correctly into that one and then I used additional `INSERT/SELECT` to put it in the correct format.

Comment: @petrch optionally enclosed by gives an error. Do I need to list the fields as well to use this? Can you put it in a solution for me por favor? I'm ignoring field headers (IGNORE 1 LINES)

Comment: _That_ "garbage table" could _not_ have come from _that_ CSV file.  For example, "gallon keg" does not exist in the CSV file; there is no way for MySQL to conjure up words, no matter how drunk you think it is.

Comment: @RickJames I used "etc... " to indicate that the csv has more entries. It actually has 2000+ entries. I would get destroyed by mods for pasting everything, but I suppose I could have pastebined it. The issue is resolved anyhow.

Comment: @LeoScarano - See if you can find the rows in the CSV that say "gallon keg".  If we can see the "before" and "after" it may be obvious what transformation is occurring.  Then it may be obvious what was done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a table based on your description (`Average_Price` I added an underscore)

```
 create table Alcohol (
   name varchar(45), 
   Type varchar(45), 
   ABV FLOAT, 
   Brewery INT(11), 
   Average_Price DOUBLE, 
   Description VARCHAR(1000)
);
```

I loaded your example file like this

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/alcohol.csv' INTO TABLE Alcohol FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

And I think I got reasonable results:

```
 `SELECT * from Alcohol;
```

```
+--------------------------+------+------+---------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| name                     | Type | ABV  | Brewery | Average_Price | Description                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
+--------------------------+------+------+---------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Hocus Pocus              | Beer |  4.5 |     812 |             0 | Our take on a classic summer ale.  A toast to weeds, rays, and summer haze.  A light, crisp ale for mowing lawns, hitting lazy fly balls, and communing with nature, Hocus Pocus is offered up as a summer sacrifice to clodless days.Its malty sweetness finishes tart and crisp and is best apprediated with a wedge of orange. |
| Grimbergen Blonde        | Beer |  6.7 |     264 |             0 | None                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| Widdershins Barleywine   | Beer |  9.1 |     779 |             0 | None                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| Lucifer                  | Beer |  8.5 |     287 |             0 | None                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| Bitter                   | Beer |    4 |    1056 |             0 | None                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| Winter Warmer            | Beer |  5.2 |    1385 |             0 | None                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| Winter Welcome 2007-2008 | Beer |    6 |    1099 |             0 | None                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
|                          | NULL | NULL |    NULL |          NULL | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
+--------------------------+------+------+---------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
</code>
```

Comment: I don't get this result without the inclusion of a line terminator '\r\n' on my windows box.

Comment: I removed all commas from my description line replaced them with a special char. Then I used this command, and replaced the special char with a ',' in MySQL when the tables were loaded. This was because some of my description fields werent enclosed by quotations. Thank y'all for your help!

Comment: Well, windows makes things sometimes more difficult. I did it on linux in my virtualbox. In that case I would suggest also to provide the CHARACTER SET as explained here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html. Also, make sure that youre server/table and client character sets do match (e.g. `\s` in the client shows that). The `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY` says that if the column is in quotes it will ignore commas as column separators.